# In-class initialization of std::unique_ptr to an incomplete type

Tags: c++, unique-ptr, incomplete-type

I can't get the following code to compile with `clang-cl` in Visual Studio 2019. Though `VC++` compiles it successfully. Also it works with custom deleter. Is it supposed to work as it is in the example? And if not, why?

`example.h`

```
#include <memory>

class A;

class B {
    std::unique_ptr<A> a{ make_a() };
    std::unique_ptr<A> make_a();
public:
    B(); ~B();
};
```

`example.cpp`

```
#include "example.h"

class A {};

std::unique_ptr<A> B::make_a() {
    return std::unique_ptr<A>(new A());
}

B::B() = default;
B::~B() = default;
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "example.h"

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

> error : invalid application of 'sizeof' to an incomplete type 'A'

Comment: please share the error messages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it supposed to work as it is in the example?

Yes, the example should work. Defining `B::~B` after `A` is complete is sufficient (and necessary).

Some standard rules:

> [unique.ptr.general]
>
> ... The template parameter T of unique_­ptr may be an incomplete type.

> [unique.ptr.dltr.dflt]
>
> The template parameter T of default_­delete may be an incomplete type.

---

As an aside, minor suggestion:

```
std::unique_ptr<A>
B::make_a() {
    return std::make_unique<A>();
}
```

Comment: Could you tell what compiler you use?

Comment: @Oleksa Clang and GCC on Linux.

Comment: Do you think Clang on Windows may differ somehow?

Comment: @Oleksa If the shown example doesn't work, then the compiler or the standard library implementation evidently seems to differ.